# Maven assembly - separate jar and dependecies

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have a parent project with multiple jar project and I'm using a specific child project to assembly zip package with all jar and dependencies, indeed I added all my project as dependencies of this specific project.

Is there any way to separate jar and dependencies in two different zip?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i can think about, is to use two assembly descriptors.

**pom.xml:**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly-myjars.xml</descriptor>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**assembly-myjars.xml:**

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>myjars</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <includes>
                <include>your.groupId:*</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

**assembly-dependencies.xml:**

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>your.groupId:*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```